# Removing gridview edit column from .Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I am working on an enterprise project. So, there are many users from data entry operators to the higher management. User accounts are separately stored in **UserData Table** and their respective privileges in the **userprivileges table**.

Multiple forms in my gridview support transaction for which I have provided **View, edit, update** options as below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvId".....>
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField..... />
     .
     .
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                  CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" 
                  CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                  CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
          </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I want to do is that, **based on session (user currently logged in)**, I have to set the visibility of the **EDIT** and **DELETE** functionality in the gridview.

**UPDATE:** Can this be implemented in the .Master page and a call from the subsidiary pages be possible?

Comment: Do you want to show/hide the entire column, or the individual buttons?

Comment: The entire column. The admin has all rights. The mid level workers will have add rights. Data Entry operators can Add data but not delete. Things like that.

Comment: Instead of using the Master page it'd be better to create a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView and place the security checks there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C# Code-Behind, check the current user and check there Privileges.

Once you have determined this you can then simply hide the column :

```
if (!userEdit) {
    grvId.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Where the `0` is the column number of the Edit Column (Remember collections start at 0) and the `userEdit` variable is a boolean set on whether the user can Edit the grid or not.

Comment: I shall give this a try @Nunners. But, instead of placing it in the induvidual form, can this be done in the .Master page?

Comment: @Mahe Yes you can place this in a Master Page, use the following code to access the GridView from the master page (Please note that the GridView ID must be the same) `GridView gv = (GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("grvId");`. You should also check to see if the value found is null to avoid errors should the GridView not exist.

Comment: Do you mean, the grid doesnt exist at all. Or, the grid has still not been bound with values? - @Nunners? Please clarify. The first case, yes. There are about 3 reports which are such. Only grid is declared. Even the columns are created based on sql query output from the user.

Comment: @Mahe The check for null will only be to check if the GridView control actually exists on the page, whether or not the data is bound at that moment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering the question, but in this situation I would use a CommandField (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of multiple Button/Template columns:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvId" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField..... />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you can dynamically show/hide buttons like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool canEdit = isAdmin || isEditor;
    bool canDelete = isAdmin;

    // fetch the last column, which is the command field
    CommandField col = (CommandField)grvId.Columns[grvId.Columns.Count - 1];

    col.ShowEditButton = canEdit;
    col.ShowDeleteButton = canDelete;
}
```

Where of course you need to replace isAdmin, isEditor etc. with your actual permission check.

Comment: Changing it into command field cannot be done in my case as it causes all the pages(mostly) and their respective calls to be changed accordingly. Since this is an ERP project, doing so consumes a deal of time, which you don't want if you are working on a deadline.